# To follow the Symfony 2 code guidelines, should I use StudlyCase for acronyms or UPPERCASE?

Tags: symfony, coding-style, naming-conventions

In other words, should I name my class `AcmeBundle\ETL\Transform` or `AcmeBundle\Etl\Transform`?

EDIT

I found examples in the symfony core code to follow either case:

```
Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation (HTTP)
Symfony\Bridge\Monolog\Handler\FirePHPHandler (PHP)
```

In the end, I went with StudlyCase in my code.

Comment: If code guidelines exist for Symfony 2, and this particular case isn't on there, it might be worth asking on the devs mailing list. If a consensus is reached, the written guidelines can presumably be edited with a clarification.

Comment: @halfer Good answer. If you add it as one, I'll give you the green check mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If code guidelines exist for this framework, it would be worth asking for advice from the core contributors. You could do so on the [devs mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/symfony-devs), which may lead to a clarification in the written guidelines themselves.

Answer (score 2):

ETL is the short version for StudlyCase ExtractTransformLoad .
So you should probably use the first solution.

Comment: I did mention in the title that I'm asking about acronyms. But in the end, the name I'm using is "etl", not "extracttransformload". Also, I don't follow your logic: what reasoning lead you from "it's an acronym" to "use upper case"?

Comment: What I mean here is that UPPERCASE is StudlyCase for words with length 1 . And I suggest you use uppercase for acronyms because it is the most common way to write acronyms.